# Finding it difficult to understand the logic of separating Pro Webmasters, Stack Exchange and Programmers?

Tags: discussion

As a web-developer/webmaster/sysadmin (a fairly common role), I'm confused as to the separation between the different communities.

I *get* that building HTML for a webpage is more of a coding question, while SEO is more of a webmaster question. However, many of these boundaries are very blurry, and I see questions closed as 'not being a webmaster question'.

If I build a reputation on Webmasters that allows me to ask a question and put a bounty because I want an answer, it might get closed for being off-topic, even though it's closely related to being a webmaster. (Say a question on how to code a sitemap - something webmasters need to do, though technically a coding question.)

This discourages me from spending a lot of time building a reputation on one of the smaller Stack Exchange sites. I'm sure you've discussed this before, but I couldn't see an answer as to why there are these boundaries, and why my reputation doesn't flow between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, many of these boundaries are very blurry

Yes, that's how things are in the real world. :)

My guidance is here:
[If all SysAdmin questions get punted to ServerFault, and all HTML/CSS are 'programming' - what is left for ProWebmasters?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/if-all-sysadmin-questions-get-punted-to-serverfault-and-all-html-css-are-progra/406#406)

> If I build a reputation on Webmasters that allows me to ask a question and put a bounty because I want an answer, it might get closed for being off-topic

Bountied questions can't be closed by definition, unless a moderator intervenes. Also, you can't start a bounty for at least 2 days after asking; see https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty

I think your fears of questions being closed is a bit unfounded. If you are willing to ...

- read the first few paragraphs of the https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq
- browse through the front page and see what kinds of questions generally exist, and which get upvoted and downvoted

... *before* posting your question, I think you will do just fine!

It's the users who don't think at *all* before posting, and certainly don't ask on meta as you have, that we tend to have issues with.